# display CurrentUserName on list form web part

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, peoplepicker

I have a requirement to display the currently logged in user on a **newItem** list form the user is filling out- I have a people picker control which I know I can convert to the Rich Text format to display the current user.
However, I am having trouble getting the current user. I took a look at how SP did it, but found that they also had "Welcome " embedded into their code, so I cannot just re-use it.

Then I found [this resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spdsupport/archive/2008/07/25/data-view-data-form-parameters-you-don-t-know-about.aspx) that showed me how to get the logged on user from the server variable. But I have no idea to display it on the form, so I don't even know if it got what I was actually looking for!
While I was poking around the code for the page, I found that I'd already had the following parameter

```
<ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
<xsl:param name="UserID" />
```

which looked like it might do the trick, but again.... I can't figure out how to display the value of it on the webpart form- so I don't even know.

How can I display the value of a parameter on webpart page so that I can verify that it is what I am looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<xsl:value-of select="$UserID" />`  to display current user name.